# In Membership table update password with UserId

Tags: c#, asp.net, membership-provider

I used **Membership provider** to my application,
and also Created **Admin Panel** to my application

and In admin panel showing all Users that are registered to my application in a dropdown 
and Allowing admin to Edit,Delete

For **Delete an user** I used this code...

```
Membership.DeleteUser(UserName, true);
```

But for **Change Password** , How should i proceed (With me **UserId availble**)

Answer (score 0):

You really need to provide more information, are you loading all these users from a database?
if so this sql statement should do it:

```
Update Membership set password = "new pass" where userID = id
```

but truely, try providing more information and to better structure your questions

Answer (score 0):

Which MembershipProvider are you using? There are many, SimpleMembershipProvider, SqlMembershipProvider, etc. Or you are using a custom MembershipProvider?

If you are using `SimpleMembershipProvider`, ChangePassword operation is as simple as calling ChangePassword on `WebSecurity`, e.g.:

```
WebSecurity.ChangePassword(WebSecurity.CurrentUserName, oldPassword, newPassword);
```

If you are using SqlMembershipProvider, you can do something similar to below code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ChangePassword(ChangePasswordModel model)
{
    string errorMsg = "";

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // ChangePassword will throw an exception. We rather
        // want to return false in certain failure scenarios.
        bool changePasswordSucceeded;

        try
        {
            MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
            changePasswordSucceeded = currentUser.ChangePassword(model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            changePasswordSucceeded = false;
            errorMsg = ex.Message;
        }

        return Json(new { Validated = changePasswordSucceeded, Message = errorMsg }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    return View();
}
```

Please revert with any follow up question you may have.

Comment: Yes perfect.. but i am not having old password with me, just UserId/UserName and New Password.. So in that how should i do

Comment: If user wants to change their password, they must know old password. If they forgotten their password, then its ResetPassword operation, for which you just need user name.